# Is there any way to get a list of child states in angular-ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am building an angular app and for part of the app, I want to have a menu with options dynamically populated based on available states.  Here is a simplified piece of my state config:

```
$stateProvider.state('root.type.list.controls', {
  url: '/controls',
  templateUrl: 'views/controls.html',
  controller: 'ControlsCtrl',
  data: {
    title: 'Controls'
  }
})
.state('root.type.list.items', {
  url: '/items',
  templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
  controller: 'ItemsCtrl',
  data: {
    title: 'Items'
  }
})
```

I'd like to be able to populate a dropdown menu with the titles from every immediate child of the `'root.type.list'` state, based on what is in the `data` section of the config.  Is there any way to get a list of all child states for a particular state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using `$state.get()` and doing the following:

```
function _children(stateName) {
  return _.filter($state.get(), function(config) {
    return stateName === config.name.slice(0, stateName.length) &&
      config.name.split('.').length === stateName.split('.').length + 1;
  });
}
```